# Collapse of Lehman Brothers: What did they have in their books?

Tags: finance, data-request, financial-crises

What kind of products did Lehman Brothers have on their books that caused the collapse? Do we have access to data on this topic?

Answer (score 3):

We do have information on this topic. I’d recommend starting with the [Financial Crisis Inquiry Commission report chapter](http://fcic-static.law.stanford.edu/cdn_media/fcic-reports/fcic_final_report_chapter18.pdf) on it, and review the [New York Fed article](https://www.newyorkfed.org/medialibrary/media/research/epr/2014/1412flem.pdf) on its resolution. Detailed information on the assets should be available from bankruptcy filings, though those will involve quite a bit of work to obtain.

Comment: Wow, what a controversial answer.